# Regex expression not filtering special symbols

Tags: c#, regex

I'm currently using the following line of code:

```
Regex Regex_Alpha = new Regex(@"[a-zA-Z]+('[a-zA-Z])?[a-zA-Z]*");
```

What I want to do is filter the input of text fields with the condition that input should only be letters and the apostrophe symbol (actually, I still want to add more, but I'm trying to resolve this first).

Right now, it is accepting ALL characters, even numbers.

With my understanding of Regex, I tried to formulate my own expression in the line of:

```
Regex Regex_Alpha = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z'-"+$);
```

It filters numbers, but doesn't accept the apostrophe symbol. Tried to remove the @ sign and filter the apostrophe with the backslash escape character, but still no use.

What should be the best approach to filter the input so that it only accepts letters and apostrophe? (I'll do the rest of the symbols once I understand how this one should work)

Comment: Your first expression looks like you're trying to do "only letters, with a single optional apostrophe, as long as the apostrophe isn't at the start or end". Is that what you're after?

Comment: @Rawling, for now yes, but I might need to add more filters later like adding the hyphen and the dot characters. I just need the apostrophe to work since I've been trying to work my way around the regex, but I still can't solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've commented, your first regular expression is a pretty good shot at "letters, with a single apostrophe not at either end". However, it matchs any string with even a *single* letter because a regular expression looks for *any* match in the input, not for whether the *entire* input matches.

You can fix this by doing what you've done in your second regular expression - just put a `^` at the start and a `$` at the end. This means the start and end of the expression have to match the start and end of the input, so it ensures the *whole* input is only made up of letters and a possible apostrophe.

Regarding your second regular expression, you have a few of problems.

- If you want a double-quote in a `@"..."` string literal, you need to put *two* double quotes. (I think this might just be a typing mistake in your question, as what you currently have wouldn't even compile.)
- You need to close your character class with a `]`, otherwise the `[` and everything inside just get treated as a sequence of characters to match, one after the other.
- If you want a hyphen in a character class, it has to go at the start or end, or it gets mistaken for a "between" hyphen (as in `A-Z`).

The expression `@"^[a-zA-Z'""-]+$"` should match "any string entirely made of letters, apostrophes, quotes or hyphens".

Comment: That was just a typographical error, sorry. I think the problem isn't with my regex anymore, as I trust your answer to be correct, so is my earlier experiments, but still the problem occurs. I'll just re-check what could've been wrong with my methods, as I've put the Regex declaration on a separate class and I just call the methods to validate strings. Thanks.

Comment: @Jack I'm somewhat bemused by your edit. (I don't mind, I'm just curious what it's about.)

Comment: It's because of [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167342/close-all-the-typo-questions); since your post covers more than just a typo, the question should not be closed as "too localized"; I'm preventing that from happening by removing the word "typo" in your answer :)